# Node/MySQL (mysql2) Connection Pools

Tags: mysql2, node-mysql

I have a high-level question about how connection pools work in a Node application using [node/mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2).

Let's say there are two simultaneous https calls making API requests. The API (Express/Node app) invokes a function that queries my database and returns JSON.  My pool configuration has a limit of 10 connections.  When those two API calls come in, is mysql2 going to create a pool of 20 connections (each API call is treated separately with its own pool) or does mysql2 create just 10 connections total that the API will share?  What happens if 100 people connect at once?  Is that a potential pool of 1,000 database connections all at once?

The reason I ask is:  some of my API calls involve MySQL transactions and, for those requests, I want to limit the number of pool connections to just 1 so that the BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK commands all happen on the same threadId.  All of the other API calls can use whatever connection is available.

Is that logic wrong?

I'm concerned that if I limit some API call to 1 connection and let other API calls have 10 or more, I'll be causing a database connectivity issue if traffic spikes.

Thanks